# Env variables set in GitHub Actions workflow not accessible in AWS lambda project

Tags: aws-lambda, github-actions, chalice

I have a Chalice (AWS lambda Python framework) project the following CI/CD GitHub Action workflow:

```
name: Production Workflow

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "main"

env:
  REPO: ${{ github.repository }}
  GITHUB_REF_NAME: ${{ github.ref_name }}
  GITHUB_SHA: ${{ github.sha }}

jobs:
  production:
    name: Deploy production
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: "3.9"

      - name: Install requirements
        run: pip3 install -r requirements.txt

      - name: Configure AWS Credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-region: ${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}

      - name: Check branch
        run: echo "${{ env.GITHUB_REF_NAME }}"

      - name: Check branch
        run: echo "${{ env.GITHUB_SHA }}"

      - name: Run tests
        run: python3 -m unittest discover -s tests

      - name: Deploy with Chalice
        run: chalice deploy --stage=production
```

However, from inside the project, the env variables `REPO`, `GITHUB_REF_NAME` and `GITHUB_SHA` are not accessible (i.e. `os.environ.get("GITHUB_REF_NAME", None)`).  Why?

I also tried setting the env variables not globally, but in the "Deploy with Chalice" step only, with the same result. Also, I can successfully see the branch and commit ID written in GitHub Actions by the "Check branch" and "Check branch" steps.

Other env variables that are set in the Chalice config file `.chalice/config.json` are accessible.

Comment: Why would you expect chalice to set all environment variables that it sees rather than just those that are explicitly configured in the chalice config? That is (luckily) not how it works. Are you looking for a way to run `chalice deploy` while specifying addition arguments, e.g. environment variables?

Comment: I naively thought environment variables were taken from... the environment. Anyway, understood. Yes, now I wonder if I can pass that as arguments to `chalice deploy` command

Answer (score -1):

You need to set up the environment and explicitly list all ENV variables you want to use, like this:

```
- name: Deploy with Chalice
  run: chalice deploy --stage=production
  env:
     GITHUB_REF_NAME: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_REF_NAME }} 
     GITHUB_SHA: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_SHA }}
```

Comment: As said, I tried already to set the env in the dedicated step. It doesn't change anything, Chalice doesn't take the env variable, only the vars set in the config file.